# Remove BOPF Message (from /bobf/if_frw_message) via ABAP

Tags: error-handling, message, abap, sap-erp

I got an object with `TYPE REF TO /bobf/if_frw_message`.
And I need to remove some messages from object before "send it" to UI
Only I know is message class name and message number.
Which is the proper way to deal with it?

Comment: Would be great if somebody could create a tag for BOBF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed the interface only has methods to add and read. The only option you really have here is to use `GET( )` to get all the messages, instantiate a new instance of the object and add all the messages one by one using `ADD_CM( )` and then skip the one you do not need.

Question is why you need to remove the message. A part of the application wanted to report this, it would be better to suppress it at the point where it gets generated.

Comment: yep, I've done by that way (checking `if_t100_message~t100key`), looks there is no more convenient methods, thanks!